# Como criar um elemento com filho sem adicioná-lo?

Tags: javascript, html

Imagine:

```
var pai = document.createElement('div');
var filho = document.createElement('div');
```

Quero que o **filho** esteja dentro do pai antes de adicioná-lo ao documento. É impossível com pai.appendChild(filho) pois é preciso que **pai** esteja no documento antes de adicionar um filho, como proceder?

PS: não quero adicionar pai para que assim adicione o filho e depois remover pai salvando o novo formato.

Comment: serve `innerHTML` em vez de `createElement`?

Comment: @Guilherme Costamilam, innerHTML serve, mas tenho dúvidas se funcionará

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> É impossível com pai.appendChild(filho) pois é preciso que pai esteja no documento antes de adicionar um filho

Essa afirmação não é verdadeira.

Pode começar por consultar a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/DOM/element.appendChild), e confirmar que não existe nenhuma menção à afirmação que fez.

No entanto, podemos por o `appendChild` em código e ver que funciona, adicionando o nó, mesmo quando ambos não estão no DOM:

```js
var pai = document.createElement('div');
var filho = document.createElement('div');

console.log(`Pai tem ${pai.childNodes.length} filhos`); //Pai tem 0 filhos
pai.appendChild(filho);
console.log(`Pai tem ${pai.childNodes.length} filhos`); //Pai tem 1 filhos

for (let i = 0; i < pai.childNodes.length; ++i){
  console.log(`Filho ${i} é ${pai.childNodes[i].tagName}`);
}
```

Concluindo:

É de facto com a função `appendChild` que adiciona filhos a nós que não estejam ainda no DOM.

Comment: De fato, curioso, executei a função e não havia funcionado, mas agora funcionou... enfim, muito obrigado1

Answer (score 0):

Exemplo com `innerHTML`:

```
document.getElementById ('exemplo').innerHTML = '<div> 1 <div> 2 </div> </div>'
```

O elemento `exemplo` pode ser uma `div`, cuidado, se usar um container com algo dentro o conteúdo será apagado, para adicionar mais conteúdo sem apagar o que ja tem use `+=` em vez de `=`

Comment: funcionou! obrigado.